# Response Writer in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

```
ResponseWriter writer=context.getResponseWriter();
```

I want to know about `startElement`, `endElement`, and `writeAttribute` methods on `ResponseWriter`.

Comment: An implementation of javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter, of course, depends on which implementation you are using.

Comment: And why don't check it out. Or may be you are not clear enough.

Comment: I am  using it in encodeBegin method of Spinner class.

Comment: i want to know about startElement,endElement and WriteAttribute method.can You explain it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSF output is HTML/XML and a `ResponseWriter` makes it easier to generate it correctly. Say you wanted to render some text in a `<span>` tag.

```
<span>My random text</span>
```

The code would look like:

```
ResponseWriter writer=context.getResponseWriter();
writer.startElement("span", component);
writer.writeText(text, null);
writer.endElement("span");
```

`writerAttribute` comes in when you need to add an ID or class attribute to the tag.

```
ResponseWriter writer=context.getResponseWriter();
writer.startElement("span", component);
writer.writeAttribute("id", id, null);
writer.writeText(text, null);
writer.endElement("span");
```

This would render:

```
<span id="myId">My text</span>
```

Note: `writeAttribute` immediately follows `startElement`. Once you start another element or write some text, you cannot call `writeAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks, i was much worried since i could not get the concept.You made it clear.

Comment: can you explain the meaning of third parameter `property` in `writer.writeAttribute("id", id, null);`, please?