# Creating Custom Component in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to create a custom component by extending the Column class from [primefaces v7](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/column?id=column).
Yes, a very old version; unfortunately this is what the project is using right now.

```
package com.components;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;
import org.primefaces.component.column.Column;


@FacesComponent(createTag = true, tagName = "customColumn",
    namespace = "http://components.com/tags")
public class CustomColumn extends Column {

  @Override
  public String getFamily() {
    return "com.components";
  }

  @Override
  public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {

    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    writer.startElement("p:column", this);
    writer.writeAttribute("headerText", "Payment", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("id", "payment", null);
    writer.endElement("p:column");

  }
}
```

```
<cc:customColumn>
   <h:outputText value="#{document.payment}" />
</cc:customColumn>
```

I want to add some attributes to the tag but when I inspect the page, the attributes do not exist on the component. I have seen ways to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438026/response-writer-in-jsf) and [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jsf/custom-component-basic.html).

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please explain your requirements? There might be easier ways to achieve them.

Comment: Are you referring to code completion feature of the IDE you're using? (Eclipse/IntelliJ/Netbeans/etc) This is technically speaking not JSF's responsibility but IDE's responsibility. You shall then need to tell which IDE exactly you're using in order ot get better assistance on reconfiguring the IDE for this. But generally you'll need to create a `*.taglib.xml` file. By the way, you're supposed to write out HTML code, not JSF code.

Answer (score 0):

This can never work:

```
writer.startElement("p:column", this);
```

What you're rendering, lives at the client-side. There, there is no notion of `p:column`.
Some guidance on writing custom components:
https://github.com/e-Contract/enterprise-jsf/releases/download/enterprise-jsf-1.12.3/enterprise-jsf.pdf